# .htaccess ReWriteRule - Quick Question

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've created a ReWriteRule, which I think points to claim.php?claimlisting=$#

The rule is written as follows :

```
# Claim

RewriteRule ^listing/claim/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+).(.html|htm)$ claim.php?claimlisting=$1 [L]
```

An example link is : /listing/claim/anne-morrison--hypnotherapy-cognitive-behaviour-therapists

I would like my MOD_REWRITE to point to the ROOT dir and claim.php?claimlisting=$ID_HERE

I've put the file up, But it doesnt seem to be affecting the site at all? Is what I've done correct and what else would be a factor preventing it from functioning correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Claim

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^listing/claim/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+).(html|htm)$ /claim.php?claimlisting=$1 [L]
```

And you are missing .html at the end of link

Comment: Thanks SergeS as per my comment above and question, It seems that the claim.php is just not getting referenced

Comment: ok, so try remove some part of regexp and check if it works ( eg. try just ^listing/claim/$ /claim.php - if this wouldn't work - check if mod_rewrite is enabled )

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra period.

```
RewriteRule ^listing/claim/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\.(html|htm)$ claim.php?claimlisting=$1 [L]
```

I removed the one in the second set of parenthesis, and escaped the first one. Try that.

Comment: Cheers Wige. I've added that, But it doesnt seem to be having an effect on the site.